# ZSH completion of long options gives short options

Tags: git, zsh

When trying to complete for example git difftool --cached, ZSH should complete directly, but instead if gives me a lot of short options to choose from, am I doing something wrong? My current config looks like this: https://github.com/sblask/dotfiles/blob/master/zshrc.dotfile

Example:

```
$ git difftool --cac<TAB>
-0            -- omit diff output for unmerged entries
-1            -- diff against "base" version
-2            -- diff against "our branch" version
-3            -- diff against "their branch" version
-b            -- ignore changes in amount of white space
-B            -- break complete rewrite changes into pairs of given size
-C            -- detect copies as well as renames with given scope
--cached      -- show diff between index and named commit/
...
```

Comment: This works as expected for me (version 5.0.7) -- even with your zshrc. Are you using the most recent zsh version?

Comment: So `git difftool --cac<TAB>` completes to `git difftool --cached` for you? I am using 5.0.5, nothing in the release notes that points to a change that could explain it? http://zsh.sourceforge.net/releases.html

Comment: Exacty, `git difftool --cac<TAB>` completes to `git difftool --cached`, see my answer for some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compare the source tree of *zsh-5.0.5* to the one of *zsh-5.0.7*, there are quite some changes regarding *git* completion:

```
$ git diff --stat zsh-5.0.5..zsh-5.0.7 | grep _git
 Completion/Unix/Command/_git                      |  353 +++--
 Functions/VCS_Info/Backends/VCS_INFO_get_data_git |  158 ++-
```

The release notes mention only the most important changes, but not every single code change. Here are the commit messages mentioning *git* (I didn't dig into which ones are relevant for your problem...):

```
33180: _git: add missing --3way option
33177: _git: fix typo in git-apply
33178: _git: updates for Git 2.1.0
33176: _git: Add missing --list to git-tag
33179: _git: updates for Git 2.0.0
33184: vcs_info git: consider patches for rebase
33188: vcs_info git: set rrn before using it
33150: completion git: fix send-email --confirm values
33145: vcs_info git: fix applied-string name
33147: vcs_info git: detect revert or cherry-pick with multiple commits
33151: completion git: support aliases when \n exist
33047: use git to simplify massively source distribution file selection
32662: vcs_info git: Fix stagedstr for empty repos
32597: vcs_info git: Describe detached heads symbolically.
32502: fix typo in argument list for git completio
32398: _git: completion updates up to latest git v1.9.0
32397: _git: fix __git_submodules to only use the actual name of the submodule
32395: _git: diff: refactor and fix wrong completions
32396: _git: fix __git_committish_range_{first,last} and __git_is_committish_range
```

I am able to reproduce the behavior you describe with *zsh-5.0.5*, but with *zsh-5.0.7* `git difftool --cac<TAB>` completes as expected to `git difftool --cached`.

So, cut a long story short: **Upgrade your installation to zsh-5.0.7.**